# PDO Update Unsuccessfull

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo, sql-update

I am using PDO driver in the PHP framework COdeigniter..

I have two queries that I have to run once some one hits a "submit" button.

One is a insert the next (the problem query) is a update.

This is the code snippet in my model :

```
function studenttime($anum) {
    try {
        $times = NULL;

        $sql = "UPDATE student SET last_visit = :times WHERE anum = :anum";
        $time = $this -> db -> conn_id -> prepare($sql);
        $time -> bindParam(':times', $times);
        $time -> bindParam(':anum', $anum);
        $time -> execute();
        if ($time -> rowCount() == 1) {
            return $time;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e -> getMessage());
        die("An Error Occured, Contact System Admin - Err: SFM136");
    }
}
```

this is my controller :

```
} else {
                if ($session = $this -> staff_model -> session($anum, $why, $aidyear, $comments) && $time = $this -> staff_model -> studenttime($anum)) {

                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('anum');
                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('first');
                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('last');
                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('aidyear');
                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('why');
                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('comments');

                    redirect('staff_controller/studentlogin', 'location');
                }
            }
```

The first query that calls $session = session in my model works just fine...

then I try to two queries in one else statement by using the && but it doesn't seem that the second one even effects the outcome of the if statement.

I can't see what I am doing wrong here as my controller is littered with a bunch of these kinda code snippets so I can't see the issue with this particular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually occurring from my other method in my model :

```
function checkanum($anum) {
        try {
            $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE anum = : anum";
            $check = $this -> db -> conn_id -> prepare($sql3);
            $check -> bindParam(':anum', $anum);
            $check -> execute();
            if ($check -> rowCount() == 1) {
                return $check;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log($e -> getMessage());
            die("An Error Occured, Contact System Admin - Err: ST_M79");
        }
    }
```

It was equal to == 0, it should be 1.

my controller was to check if a record already existed, if it did then just update the time it was queried again. I figured it out when I purposefully misspelled one of the assignments in the if statement, I noticed it wasn't giving errors, that gave me the info needed to determine that my logic was flawed. All is working perfectly now.

Thanks for your inputs. and I like the addition that Oscar added :

> This should work better:
>
> if (($session = $this -> staff_model -> session($anum, $why, $aidyear,
>   $comments)) && ($time = $this -> staff_model -> studenttime($anum))) {
>
> I would advice you avoid multiple assignments in if-statements like
>   that simply because, well, it's confusing!

makes a lot of sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's due to operator precedence.

Try running this code for an example:

```
if ($a = 5 && $b = 6) {
    var_dump($a); // Output: bool(true)
}
```

Why? Because it's the same as this:

```
if ($a = (5 && $b = 6)) {
    var_dump($a); // Output: bool(true)
}
```

Moral of the story: put parentheses around assignments inside if-statements and similar.

This should work better:

```
if (($session = $this -> staff_model -> session($anum, $why, $aidyear, $comments)) && ($time = $this -> staff_model -> studenttime($anum))) {
```

I would advice you avoid multiple assignments in if-statements like that simply because, well, it's confusing!

Comment: This didnt work either. all my queries except for the one i posted in the OP work. this is really weird...

Answer (score 0):

You should make your if statements easier to read, both for you and for anyone else who is going to read the code. Also, don't assign values to variables in the middle of an if statement, everything should be decided by the time you get there, just because the programming language can handled variables assignments in an if statement doesn't mean that it is going to work the way you think they're going to work.

```
$a = $session = $this -> staff_model -> session($anum, $why, $aidyear, $comments);
$b = $time = $this -> staff_model -> studenttime($anum);
```

Now you can do something like.

```
if($a && $b)
{
    //...
}
```

And if you're really trying to unset all the sessions you have active, then you can use

```
session_destroy();
```

but if you're only trying to destroy a subset then sure, do it the way you're doing it.

I don't know if the $a and $b I posted are correct (copy/paste from you), but my point is simply that once you structure your code better then it becomes easier to crack the problem.